# How do I get Enum key from a value in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, enums

I'm having this problem in a large project, so I've tried to simplify my problem to this example:

```js
enum Screens {
    Home,
    About
}

interface HomeData {
    title: string
    posts: string[]
}

interface AboutData {
    title: string
}

interface PageData {
    [Screens.Home]: HomeData
    [Screens.About]: AboutData
}

const pageData: PageData = {
    [Screens.Home]: { title: 'Home', posts: ['intro', 'care'] },
    [Screens.About]: { title: 'Home' }
}

const addData = (screen: Screens, data: PageData[typeof screen]) => {
    pageData[screen] = data; //error here, Type 'HomeData | AboutData' is not assignable to type 'HomeData & AboutData'.
}
```

Im trying to dynamically pass the data object to the function and assign it to the corresponding screen, but typescript dosen't seem to understand that `pageData[screen]` is tied to the first argument of the function: `screen`, it thinks that the argument `data` must satisfy `HomeData & AboutData`.

I know there are probably other ways to implement this, but my codebase is very intertwined to this structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the generic parameter for the `screen` and get the data of that specific `screen`:

```
const addData = <T extends Screens>(screen: T, data: PageData[T]) => {
  pageData[screen] = data;
};
```

Usage:

```
addData(Screens.Home, { posts: [], title: "" }); // no error
addData(Screens.About, { posts: [], title: "" }); // expected error
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/KYOwrgtgBAygxgJ2KAzlA3gWAFBSgCQHsJgAaHPAQQCNCwAXc7AXxxwEsR7gEAzAQzjACxYABF+9fhgpR67egBtgALigp6CTgHMA3LIAOhDSjUatIbQG0AuvpZtsnbn0HCadehKkzcchcpmmjr2rNgcXDwCQlAACvza4pLSWH5W8EioAHREJDZquUlS9njpiMggKFkeDPlQNV7JoY5whJX0UAYJRfxq8Yne0gC8vqUZFVWFdej+SqpQAESFC6SdxvSmUFYLzgiEK4tw-EgLNlDMTGPl2Q3Ts4GLy+dMzPY4re1Q-AAm34NQIwAPAAVKDAAAe3BA3zQ41QAD4ABQoa4gNTA1bfZJ9bqDKzAmwASgB8NGnVxySsKMyIDOIyxxRwr0cPz+yURcMqOVEqxmRhMalsq3kczUCwW50J9lZgw5qKqDV5awFWxswoC83Fkt0UAA9LqweCDMA4NxvmCEHsEDggA)